# Subsequent callbacks from a Cordova iOS plugin don't fire

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have troubles with firing immediately subsequent callbacks from a cordova plugin (an iOS one).
In XCode debugger I clearly see it steps over

```
[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:monitoredRegions.callbackId];
```

several times (in immediate succession), each time with a slightly different `pluginResult`.
That gets triggered by

```
[locationManager requestStateForRegion:region];
```

which I don't (and can't) control.

The problem is, on the Javascript side, the callback gets fired only once.

What's (actually not so) strange is that if I introduce some blocking in that callback, like `alert()`, the callback gets fired several times (as expected). That's cool but I don't need any `alert()` in the app.

If I understand it, the `commandDelegate` should take care of threading and queueing, but it seems like it doesn't. The question is, how to get the JS callback fired each time `sendPluginResult` gets called.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So, the issue wasn't in threading/queueing.

It turned out that you are allowed to use a `callbackId` only once **unless** you tell Cordova not to cleanup that `callbackId` by setting `CDVPluginResult.keepCallback` to `true`. Pay attention that `keepCallback` isn't a `BOOL` property, so you may need to call `[pluginResult setKeepCallbackAsBool:YES];`

```
CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [sendPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:key];
[pluginResult setKeepCallbackAsBool:YES]; // here we tell Cordova not to cleanup the callback id after sendPluginResult()
[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:monitoredRegions.callbackId];
```

What messes things up is that if you introduce a blocking call like `alert()` in that callback, Cordova will let you make multiple successive `sendPluginResult` with the same `callbackId`.

Keep in mind that you may need to `sendPluginResult` with a `CDVPluginResult` which `keepCallback` is `false` to release the `callbackId` that you don't need anymore.

Comment: Thank you for explaining what setKeepCallback does. I've been banging my head on this scenario.

Comment: I had `pluginResult.keepCallback = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];` and it simply did not work. I changed it to `[pluginResult setKeepCallbackAsBool:YES];` and it magically worked!

Comment: Thank you @meandre, I've had the same problem